# state value getting lost even after storing it in localstorage [React/React-router]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I make a request to the api and in return I get "hello". I **store this hello in a test_text** variable and later in return I would **want to redirect user to another url if test_text is not set.** Else I would want to present a component.

This code is **working properly UNTIL I refresh** the page.

**After refreshing** the page, for some reason, **test_text is being set back to "" (empty string)** which is therefore redirecting me back to "/" url. This is **confusing because using UseEffect, I am storing "hello" in localstorage and using another useEffect I am trying to get the "hello" text from localstorage.** Here's the code. Please help me.

```
import {React,useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import Landing from './components/landing/LandingIndex';
import Home from './components/home/HomeIndex';

function App() {

    const [test_text, setText_text] = useState('');

    useEffect(()=>{
        const data = localStorage.getItem('data');
        console.log(localStorage.getItem('data')); // hello
        if(data){
            setText_text(JSON.parse(data));
        }
    },[])

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('/sessionDetails', {
            method: 'POST',
            cache: 'no-cache',
            headers: {
                'content_type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify()
        }).then(response => {
            return response.json()
        }).then(json => {
            console.log(json.result_text) // hello
            setText_text(json.result_text);
            localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(json.result_text))
        })
    },[])


    return (
        <div className='App'>
        <Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route path = '/' exact component = {Landing}/>
                <Route  exact path = '/home'>
                {test_text === '' ? <Redirect to="/" /> : <Home />}
                </Route>
            </Switch>
        </Router>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useEffect` is called **after** the component has finished rendering: See [What does useEffect do?](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks)

When your component finishes its first render:

- the `test_text` **is still equal to its initial state** i.e.  `''`.
- since `test_text === ''`, the `<Redirect>` is used when the JSX is rendered
- after all the JSX has been rendered, the `useEffect` is called to update the `test_text` state

---

**Pseudocode**

In this example, it makes sense to check that `localStorage.getItem('data')` is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy).

- if `false`, use the `<Redirect/>` component
- else use the `<Home/>` component.

---

**Code**

Try changing this line of code:

```
{test_text === '' ? <Redirect to="/" /> : <Home />}
```

to this:

```
{!localStorage.getItem('data') ? <Redirect to="/" /> : <Home />}
```

Comment: I know these kind of comments are discouraged but Thank you so much. I swear I could never have figured this out by myself. I have been trying to fix this issue since yesterday. Thank you

Comment: No problem :) I'm glad it helped.